# circles with 32 nodes

Tags: circles

[image]

to describe what the diagrams are
 - there is a larger circle for each step
 - each larger circle has 32 nodes
 - the arrows indicate the direction to move the cords

i have installed LatTex so what addin do i need to do this?

any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get familiar with Ti*k*Z. You can use the code below as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\let\twodigits\two@digits
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=9},cord/.style={-stealth,thick}]
\begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=-1]
\draw (0:0) circle (2);
\draw (0:0) circle (.3);
\foreach \x in {45,90,...,360}
  \draw (\x:.3) -- (\x:2);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {5.625,16.875,...,354.375}
  \coordinate (n\i) at (\x:2.2);
\foreach[evaluate={\j=int(2*\i+2)}] \x [count=\i] in {16.875,39.375,...,354.375}
  \node at (\x:1.8) {\footnotesize \twodigits\j};
\end{scope}

\node[node] at (n1) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n2) {};
\node[node] at (n8) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n9) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n10) {};
\node[node] at (n11) {};
\node[node] at (n15) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n16) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n17) {};
\node[node] at (n18) {};
\node[node] at (n23) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n24) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n25) {};
\node[node] at (n26) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n31) {};
\node[node] at (n32) {};

\draw[cord,out=290,in=300,looseness=5] (n31) to (n30);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=9},cord/.style={-stealth,thick}]
\begin{scope}[rotate=90,yscale=-1]
\draw (0:0) circle (2);
\draw (0:0) circle (.3);
\foreach \x in {45,90,...,360}
  \draw (\x:.3) -- (\x:2);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {5.625,16.875,...,354.375}
  \coordinate (n\i) at (\x:2.2);
\foreach[evaluate={\j=int(2*\i+2)}] \x [count=\i] in {16.875,39.375,...,354.375}
  \node at (\x:1.8) {\footnotesize \twodigits\j};
\end{scope}

\node[node] at (n1) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n2) {};
\node[node] at (n8) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n9) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n10) {};
\node[node] at (n11) {};
\node[node] at (n15) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n16) {};
\node[node] at (n18) {};
\node[node] at (n23) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n24) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n25) {};
\node[node] at (n26) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n30) {};
\node[node,fill] at (n31) {};
\node[node] at (n32) {};

\draw[cord,bend left=10] (n30) to (n17);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]